# How to show and hide paging toolbar using sencha touch?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have small requirement i.e. PDFViewer in sencha touch, default paging toolbar is hidden.Once we click on pdf document the paging toolbar is showned, remaining time it is hidden.Here my problem is paging toolbar is not showned and hidden.
I tried the following code.Can you please suggest me.
Here is my code

```
samplePdf = {
 xtype : 'pdfpanel',
 id: 'pdfViewer', src :'http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/tracemonkey.pdf',
 scrollable: true,
 hidePagingtoolbar: false,
 listeners: {
      tap: {
          fn: function() {
                paging = Ext.getCmp('pdfViewer');
                if(samplePdf.hidePagingtoolbar==false){
                  hidePagingtoolbar:true
                 //Ext.getCmp('pdfViewer').hidePagingtoolbar.hide();
                }
                else{ 
                 hidePagingtoolbar: true;
                }
              },
     element: 'element'},}};
```

Thanks,
Rajasekhar.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the "getter/setter" of the "HidePagingtoolbar" object e.g.

```
listeners: {
  tap: {
      fn: function() {
            paging = Ext.getCmp('pdfViewer');
            paging.setHidePagingtoolbar(!paging.getHidePagingtoolbar());
          }
    }
}
```

That should toggle the HidePaggingToolbar flag.